# Django - limit choices to foreign key

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have the following model in Django

```
class Transfer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, limit_choices_to={'is_accepted':True})
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    transfer_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I would like to filter the users based on is_accepted field. The problem is, that this field is declared in a model called Employee, which is in onetoone relationship with user.
Is there any possibility to reach Employee fields and filter them in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can normally define a filter like:

```
class Transfer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        limit_choices_to={'employee__is_accepted': True}
    )
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    transfer_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Comment: Great and quick answer! Thanks!